# Greater number among number stored in a set of variables

Tags: vb.net

I have 10 number in a set a variables. (say: 25, 33, 11, 4, 3.................)
I want to get the biggest number in a message.

How do I get it?
Thanks 
Furqan

Comment: Don't have the numbers in a set of variables, use a collection and the [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx) extension method.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework question. So, if you'll forgive me, I'm not going to give a direct answer.

What you might want to look at is [Math.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx). You loop over the numbers and store the result of each Math.Max and the value stored at the end is the largest number that you have.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the numbers are passed as an array (or any Enumerable such as List), this code will do the work for you

```
Dim numbers() = New Integer(){25, 33, 11, 4, 3}
Dim max = numbers.Max()

MsgBox("Maximum number is: " & max)
```

---

I seriously think this is a homework though.